# Take two arrays and return only unique values

Tags: javascript, arrays

I've been searching for a (better) way to do the following. Take two arrays and return only the unique values. E.g. ['value1', 'value2'] and ['value2', 'value3'] should return 'value1' and 'value3'. The following seems to work but I was wondering if there was an easier/more concise way to achieve the same result.

```
function diffArray(arr1, arr2) {
  var newArr = arr1.filter(function(a) {
    var count = 0;
    arr2.forEach(function (x) {
      if (x === a) {count++;}
    });
    if (count !== 0) {return false;}
    return true;
  }).concat(arr2.filter(function(b) {
    var count = 0;
    arr1.forEach(function(y) {
      if (y === b) {count++;}
    });
    if (count !== 0) {return false;}
    return true;
  }));
  return newArr;
}

console.log(diffArray([1, 2, 3, 5], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]));
//Should return only 4.
```

Comment: Change the tag to JS, and look at Sets https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set

Comment: Sorry about that guys.

Comment: FYI for set difference, A - B = x forall x in A, x not in B. So the semantics of your diff algorithm are different than the semantics of set difference. You will most likely need symmetric difference https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_difference

Comment: I don't understand why `[v1, v2] and [v2, v3]` return only `v3`? Doesn't return `[v1, v3]`?

Comment: So what's the actual question?  If it's "is there a better way", that question is too broad.

Comment: @Iluvatar I've scanned the page and it seems that Sets restrict what's in it to be unique. However, I'm trying to get the value that only appears once between two arrays and not only 1 of each value.

Comment: @Fefux You're right. It should return both 'value1' and 'value3'. Edited post.

Comment: @ryanyuyu I feel like my current solution takes up too much space. I've also heard that using methods like the Array.forEach take more resources.

Comment: Make a set of each, say `A` and `B`, then do `(A-B)+(B-A)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A fixed version of Th0rndike's answer:

```js
var a1=[1,2];
var a2=[2,3];

function diffArray(a1,a2){
    return a2.filter(function(item){
       return a1.indexOf(item) < 0;
    }).concat(a1.filter(function(item){
       return a2.indexOf(item) < 0;
    }));
}

console.log(diffArray(a1,a2));
```

Answer (score 1):

If you can use a library i suggest to use lodash.
The have a generic N array operation for that.

```
_.xor([2, 1], [2, 3]);
```

https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.2#xor

Comment: Thanks for pointing me to the library. However, I'm still wondering if there's a "better" way to do it in vanilla JS.

Comment: This is JavaScript. See the code ;-) https://github.com/lodash/lodash/blob/4.5.0-npm-packages/lodash.xor/index.js#L879